# Wine: could not load kernel32.dll, status c0000135 Kali Linux

Tags: kernel, kali-linux, wine, winetricks

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/opt]
└─# git clone https://github.com/tokyoneon/B2E.git 
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/opt]
└─# cd B2E/
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/opt/B2E]
└─# sudo apt install wine wine64 wine32 winbind winetricks    
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/opt/B2E]
└─# dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install wine32:i386
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/opt/B2E]
└─# wine 'Bat_To_Exe_Converter_(Installer).exe'                                  
wine: could not load kernel32.dll, status c0000135
```

There are not much solutions for this error. Any suggestions?

Not sure why I got -4 since I explained what I did and if you try to search on your own, you will also experience there is a really mess about this issue. Not clear solution.

Here is also my Linux version if it helps:

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[~]
└─# wine --version
wine-7.0 (Debian 7.0~repack-10)
                                                                                                                              
┌──(root㉿kali)-[~]
└─# cat /etc/os-release                                   
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
VERSION="2022.4"
VERSION_ID="2022.4"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID=kali
ID_LIKE=debian

┌──(root㉿kali)-[~]
└─# uname -a                      
Linux kali 6.0.0-kali5-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.10-2kali1 (2022-12-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Same issue in Kali Linux, when I want to use "wine" to run "shellter.exe".

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/usr/share/windows-resources/shellter]
└─# wine shellter.exe 
wine: could not load kernel32.dll, status c0000135
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix. It is best to include relevant information such as the version of Linux and the version of the installed wine.

Comment: Basically, this seems more like a bug than a problem to ask about, and you phrased it like a bug report. As it turned out, this wasn't the case, but StackExchange isn't for bug reports, and a question is at risk if it even smells like one to begin with.

Comment: As an aside, please don't use Kali as a general desktop OS. Even its own developers tell you that that's not what it's optimized for.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue and it was probably due to misconfiguration. It worked after I got rid of old `~/.wine` folder.
Run:

```
mv ~/.wine ~/.wine.old
```

or `rm -r ~/.wine`.
Then run Wine again.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it for me.

Comment: This worked for me too! I was surprised, because I had _just_ installed Wine, on a very new VM? But I think when I ran it the first time, without the 32-bit arch installed, that created configs that were no longer true once I finished setup.

Comment: If the answer helped people, can we get the question upvoted a bit too?